# MDI Child Always on TOP C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, parent, mdi

I have a MDI Parent and two MDI Childs opened inside it. Anyone knows how do I keep only one of my MDI Childs always on top of everything?

Comment: this should help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423487/show-mdi-child-always-on-top-of-other-mdi-child

Comment: Try `BringToFront` whenever the child order changes, eg on `MdiChildActivate`

Comment: @Graham Thanks, this works for me.

Comment: Put my comment as an answer

Comment: You don't.  Change the always on top form from an MDI child to a borderless form and dock it to a side of the MDI parent instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `BringToFront` whenever the child order changes, eg on `MdiChildActivate`